# categorize a double into arbitrary bins

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, stl

I'm looking for a class that categorizes floating point numbers into arbitrary bins. The bins. The desired syntax would be something like:

```
std::vector<double> bin_vector;

// ..... fill the vector with 1, 1.4, 5, etc not evenly spaced values

Binner bins(bin_vector); 

for (std::vector<double>::const_iterator d_itr = some_vector.begin(); 
     d_itr != some_vector.end(); d_itr++) { 
  int bin = bins.categorize(*d_itr); 

  // bin would be 0 for x < 1, 1 for 1 < x < 1.4, etc
  // do something with bin
}
```

Unfortunately, due to portability requirements I'm limited to boost and stl. I've rolled my own O(log n) solutions using maps and overloading `<` for a custom range object, but that solution seemed bug prone and ugly at best.

Is there some simple stl or boost object solution to this?

Comment: Can you sort `a_vector`? Also, which operation is more critical, the construction of the `Binner` or the lookup?

Comment: @BjörnPollex yes, you can sort the vector

Comment: There is a thread on the Boost mailing list about that: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Histogram-td2591157.html A suggested solution was to use std::accumulate to collect the bin contents.

Comment: @KillianDS any range which is separated by the values in `bin_vector`

Comment: Can an index into the `vector` be a bin assignment and the size of each of your bins be `1`? (Also: you should be more clear on your desired *output*)

Comment: @TravisGockel no, I want arbitrary bins, but maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Shep: I was making a joke in that you would already have a "binning". More seriously: is `bin_vector` guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: @TravisGockel yes, it is although I think [the solution I'm looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10311085/915501) has already been posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a std::map, mapping interval boundaries to bin numbers. Then use .upper_bound() to find the bin.

Comment: ahh, yeah, that looks like it would work, also seems pretty obvious. Not sure why I didn't see that function before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an untested generic algorithm that takes an input vector of arbitrary length M and a sorted vector of N-1 bin boundaries, and that returns a vector of N bin counts. Bin i counts the values in the interval [breaks[i-1], breaks[i]). The types T1 and T2 should be mutually comparable. Complexity is equal to O(M * log (N)).

```
#include<algorithm>     // std::is_sorted, std::lower_bound
#include<cassert>       // assert
#include<iterator>      // std::distance
#include<vector>        // std::vector

template<typename T1, typename T2>
std::vector<std::size_t> bin_count(const std::vector<T1>& input, const std::vector<T2>& breaks)
{
    // breaks is a sorted vector -INF < a0 < a1 < ... < aN-2 < +INF
    assert(std::is_sorted(breaks.begin(), breaks.end()));
    auto N = breaks.size() + 1;

    std::vector<std::size_t> output(N, 0);

    if (N == 1) {
        // everything is inside [-INF, INF)
        output[0] = input.size();
        return output;
    }

    for(auto it = input.begin(), it != input.end(); ++it) {
        if (*it < breaks.front()) {
            // first bin counts values in [-INF, a0)
            ++output[0];
            break;
        }
        if (*it >= breaks.back()) {
            // last bin counts values in [aN-1, +INF)
            ++output[N-1];
            break;
        }

        const auto break_it = std::lower_bound(breaks.begin(), breaks.end(), *it);
        bin_index = std::distance(breaks.begin(), break_it) + 1;
        ++output[bin_index];
    }

    return output;  
}
```